# Can't seem to get MySQL to start in Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get MySQL to run in a Docker Container under Windows 10 WSL 2. I attempted to start the container with this command:

```
docker run -d --name mysql -v /mnt/g/DockerVolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***** -e bind-address:0.0.0 -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 mysql
```

The /mnt/g/DockerVolumes/mysql maps to a folder on an NTFS drive and not contained in the virtual drive.

The start up is aborted because the lock privilege table doesn't exist.

Below is the complete startup log.

Where did I go wrong?

NOTE: I want to keep the MySQL data files out side of a virtual hard drive for easier management AND to not fill up the system drive.

Thanks

-marc

```
2020-05-31 22:43:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-31 22:43:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-05-31 22:43:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-31T22:43:04.902473Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-05-31T22:43:04.902824Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-05-31T22:43:04.907865Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-05-31T22:43:04.945736Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.174472Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:43:06.288074Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.346697Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-31T22:43:06.438801Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.490799Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.491760Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.492104Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 18344f03-a390-11ea-9829-0242ac110002.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.643342Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-31T22:43:06.677570Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
mysqld: Cannot change permissions of the file 'private_key.pem' (OS errno 1 - Operation not permitted)
2020-05-31T22:43:06.781193Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010295] [Server] Could not set file permission for private_key.pem
2020-05-31T22:43:06.781489Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-05-31T22:43:08.628123Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-05-31 22:57:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-31 22:57:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-05-31 22:57:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-31T22:57:42.103154Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-05-31T22:57:42.103457Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-05-31T22:57:42.107950Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-05-31T22:57:42.142430Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.422720Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:57:43.537107Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.579174Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-31T22:57:43.645481Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.698518Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.700522Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.701295Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 230fcd30-a392-11ea-9633-0242ac110002.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.863312Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.911332Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-05-31T22:57:43.916234Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.918367Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.959367Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.959849Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2020-05-31T22:57:43.960109Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:57:43.960251Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.960694Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:57:43.960866Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2020-05-31T22:57:43.961186Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-05-31T22:57:45.340240Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-05-31 22:58:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-31 22:58:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-05-31 22:58:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-05-31T22:58:54.696468Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-05-31T22:58:54.696779Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-05-31T22:58:54.702278Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-05-31T22:58:54.730454Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.003162Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:58:56.209309Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.270890Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-31T22:58:56.330541Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.383656Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.384744Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.385289Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 4e62808d-a392-11ea-9118-0242ac110002.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.543387Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.581873Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-05-31T22:58:56.586523Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.588981Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010284] [Server] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.641897Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.642366Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2020-05-31T22:58:56.642657Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:58:56.642800Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.643205Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2020-05-31T22:58:56.643377Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2020-05-31T22:58:56.643668Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-05-31T22:58:57.917989Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Looks like this msg is the key: `mysqld: Cannot change permissions of the file 'private_key.pem' (OS errno 1 - Operation not permitted)`. Maybe related: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4824 ?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, thanks.  That definitely seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by not mapping the storage to a windows volume.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here - using Laradock Docker setup for my Laravel project on Windows Home WSL2 and the error `Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist` stopped MySQL container from working - the problem was with the `DATA_PATH_HOST` setup:

```
# docker/docker-compose.yml

### MySQL ################################################
    mysql:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
          - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

```
# docker/.env

# Choose storage path on your machine. For all storage systems
DATA_PATH_HOST=~/.projectname/data
```

The problem was that the magic linux home dir character `~` wasn't interpreted as the home directory but literarily - creating the data-dir for MySQL in inaccessible place and its preventing proper init - the solution is simple - just rename the data-dir to something else like:

```
# docker/.env

# Choose storage path on your machine. For all storage systems
DATA_PATH_HOST=/home/picard/.projectname/data
```

...but finding it took me half a day :(

Hopefully this will help someone to save some time :)